# How to create a public website

Tags: asp.net, iis, visual-studio-2015

I'm new to websited building, I use IIS (version 10) and Visual Studio 2015, I created a website project from an empty one in Visual Studio and I created a new website in IIS.

I'm browsing the internet with a Wi-Fi connection and an automatic IP and DNS address obtaining.

I want to make my site reachable on the internet from any computer and not only from my local host, when I change this setting in IIS and browse for the website I get the error of: "testSite.com's DNS server address was not found".

How can I fix this problem?

Thank you, Dan.

Comment: Are you behind NAT or firewall ? Can you try this command in cmd: ipconfig\flushdns. Also try opening the site via your public ip address and share your findings

Comment: I'm behind firewall, I tried that command buy it didn't help, I'm forced to type a username and password when I open the site with the public ip address

Comment: Do you have a dynamic IP address ? Also you are having a problem of NAT.